Creating GKE clusters using ansible - kubectl_path usage?
I am trying to use Ansible (with the google.cloud.gcp_container_cluster module) to create a GKE cluster, and I am encountering several issues. Mostly related to the very.... let's call it "limited" documentation available.
According to the documentation, the module should create a kubeconfig file at the path specified by kubectl_path. But, of course, no file gets created there (and there seem to be other issues with that option as well).
My question is: is there a way to use this option? If so, how?
I know that there is a workaround (which I am using right now) - install gcloud, authenticate, install the gke-gloud-auth-plugin, get the kubeconfig, and use it. But I am curious about the (still documented!) kubectl_path option.
Thank you!
